# What is the difference between declaring variables in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Could you explain the difference between declaring variables in different ways. When I should use these ways of declaring?

```
<script>
const someVariable = 12345

export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>
```

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      someVariable: 12345
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The first one is not available in the template and is not reactive (i.e. nothing updates automatically when it changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical Single File Component will be like so:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
...
</script>
```

1. If you define a variable outside the `export` statement, it is just a plain javascript variable that you can use anywhere inside the script tag. It is not bound to the component, or related to Vue in any way.
   Pros:

   - Your variable exists in the entire `<script>` element's scope.
   - You can use it inside inner functions that don't have a binding to `this`.
2. If you define a variable inside data function, or to put it more accurately, define a property for component instance's data object, then it is bound to the component, and hence available inside the `<template>` tags.
   Pros:

   - The variable can be referenced from `<template>`
   - You can take advantage of Vue's reactivity. You can define computed properties on this variable. When you use it in the template, the html is updated to reflect any change in this variable.
   - You can pass it as props to child components.
   - You can debug things easily using Vue devtools, you can watch changes to your variable. You can also log the variable into console like `$vm.data.someVarData`, i.e. the variable is added to the Vue component's instance.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div :class="someVarData"/> <!-- This is Ok -->
        <div :class="someVar"/> <!-- This is not Ok -->
    </div>
<template>
<script>
const someVar = "blah";
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            someVarData: "blahData",
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        const el = document.getElementById('myId');
        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            console.log(someVar); // This is Ok
            console.log(this.someVarData); // This is not Ok
        });
    },
    beforeRouteEnter() { // <--- Vue-router's Navigation guard
        console.log(someVar); // This is Ok
        console.log(this.someVarData); // This is not Ok
    },
</script>
```

As such you should avoid defining variables outside export since they make it harder to understand the flow of your code. There's almost always *some* way you can redesign your approach to not use variables outside export.

For e.g. in the above example, you can still use your data variable inside the `mounted` hook and the navigation guard with some changes:

```
    mounted() {
        const el = document.getElementById('myId');
        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            console.log(someVar); // This is Ok
            console.log(this.someVarData); // Ok - works because we change the function to arrow function, so it is bound to the instance's `this`
        });
        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            console.log(someVar); // This is Ok
            console.log(this.someVarData); // Ok - works because we have manually bound the function to the instance's `this`
        }.bind(this));
    },
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) { // <--- Vue-router's Navigation guard
        console.log(someVar); // This is Ok
        console.log(this.someVarData); // This is not Ok
        next((vm) => {
            console.log(vm.someVarData); // Ok - Navigation guard's next function provides the instance's context as a callback parameter
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

In the first one, you can't use the `someVariable` in your template

```
<script>
const someVariable = 12345

export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>
<template> <p> {{someVariable}} </p> </template> //doesn't work
```

#### Available in Vue3:

to make it work you can add a `setup` keyword in your script but you have to wrap your variable value with `ref(...)` or `reactive(...)` if you want to make it *reactive* to changes [More info](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html)

```
<script setup>
const someVariable = 12345

export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>
<template> <p> {{someVariable}} </p> </template> //works (you can see the data)
```